# How can I make Chromium downloaod to another drive?

Tags: permissions, hard-drive, chromium

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.  I have a 240GB ssd (/dev/sdb) where my root and home directories are.  I also have an 8TB hard drive (/dev/sda) which I'm using for storage.  My Chromium downloads folder was /home/rob/Downloads, and I would typically download to my SSD, then move files to the other drive.

I now want to download files directly to the storage drive, but I am running into permissions problems when trying to change Chromium's download destination or specifically download individual files to the storage drive.  I followed the guide [here](https://www.quora.com/Can-you-change-the-default-download-directory-in-Linux-to-another-drive) and I seem to have successfully made a symlink at /home/rob/Downloads which points to the storage drive, which I called /diskB just to match the guide.

However, I am not seeing the Downloads symlink when trying to change Chromium's download destination, or download individual files.  I see it in /home/rob when I'm in Thunar, but not in the file browser that Chromium gives me when I try to do the download.

I'm a little stuck here since I'm trying to download zip file of my online photo library, which is larger than the available space on my ssd.

How may I download directly to a drive different from my boot drive? And ideally how may I set that as the download directory for Chromium?

Edit: Adding the requested terminal output

```
rob@bighead:/media/rob/mamaw/Downloads$ ls -la
total 1551948
drwxrwxr-x 25 rob rob       4096 Dec  7 00:43  .
drwx------ 14 rob rob       4096 Mar 30  2019  ..
```

Further lines pertain to the contents of my Downloads directory.

Comment: The simplest solution is to change the Download location in your browser's settings without mucking about with symlinks and fstab and permissions. In Chrome, that's three clicks: Settings -> Advanced -> Download Location. Did you fix the permissions of your new Download directory? Did you mount that drive? If you merely edited /etc/fstab. did you reboot afterward?

Comment: I attempted Settings -> Advanced -> Download Location; that's where the permissions problem is. The drive is mounted.  I did not edit /etc/fstab; I'm not really sure what I'm doing there.  I'm still learning about handling permissions in Linux.

Comment: Learn how to use the command `ls -la` to print the complete ownership and permissions of a file or directory. Use the command `ls -la` to print the ownership and permissions of your new Downloads directory. Copy-and-paste the complete output into your question above.

Comment: How did you install Chromium? Is it a snap package?

Comment: Kulfy: It was quite a while ago, so I'm not sure, but I am almost certain I installed Chromium via the Ubuntu Software Center.